# Not run rest of code until said element exists

Tags: javascript

```
var choice1 = "hostAndPort";
var timer;

function clickerFunc() {
        timer = setInterval(checkElementExist(choice1), 500);
};

function checkElementExist(thing) {
     console.log("checkElementExist runs")
     advance = document.getElementById(thing);
     console.log(advance);
     if (advance == null){
        console.log("advance defined as null");
     } else{
        console.log("Free from loop");
        clearInterval(timer);
        clickerFunc2();
    }
};

function clickerFunc2() {
        console.log("woooooooooo");
};
```

So I've tried a suggestion below, but it still doesn't seem to work. clickerFunc is called when a button is pressed, console outputs:

```
checkElementExist runs
hostAndPort
null
advance defined as null
```

so clickerFunc2 is never called, and it does not seem to keep checking every 500 milliseconds.

UPDATE:

```
setInterval(function() { checkElementExist(choice1); },500);
```

done the trick. Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to do in general? Sounds like you're reinventing the wheel.

Comment: It seems to get stuck in the loop and never end.

Comment: updated the question since it still doesnt work with suggestions made below. im probably just being stupid.

Comment: `setInterval` takes function as a first argument so `setInterval(checkElementExist, 500);` should be to make `setInterval` work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use `while`. It will hang up the browser.

Call your rest of code from `checkElementExist`

```
function checkElementExist(id) {
     console.log("checkElementExist runs")
     advance = document.getElementById(id);
     if (advance == null){
        console.log("advance defined as null");
     }
     else{
        console.log("Free from loop");
        clearInterval(timer);
        restOfCode();
    }
};

timer = setInterval(checkElementExist('hostAndPort'), 1000);
```

--- UPDATE ---

`setInterval` takes function as a first argument so it should be like: `setInterval(checkElementExist, 1000);`. The previous code just called your function once and interval did nothing.

Comment: Polling will work, but maybe listening for a [mutation event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) will be better.

Comment: Well, old IEs don't support it. Depends on @Oxy157's requirements. I just fixed Oxy157's existing code.

Comment: setInterval was indeed the problem. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can use `return` to 'not execute the rest of the code' in a function. It does seem as though there's an easier way around your problem though. What's the exact requirement?

```
function checkElementExist(id) {
     console.log("checkElementExist runs")
     advance = document.getElementById(id);
     if (advance == null){
        return;
     }

     // rest of logic here
};
```

Comment: It is a tamper/grease monkey script. It is checking to see when a pop-up box comes up after pressing a button before running the code which will do the other necessary bits. I know the rest of the code works because I had this working using a delay using setinterval instead.

Comment: In that case, the answer provided by @phts should be sufficient.